# Are cheap sunglasses dangerous?

Tags: eye, glasses, sun-exposure, uv-rays, sunlight

Does having any plastic between your eyes and the environment automatically provide UVA and UVB protection?  Or do the lenses actually have to be coated (or be comprised of a special type of plastic) in order to afford UVA and UVB protection?

*This question is partially prompted by a shirt that I bought that prominently advertises its high level of UV protection.  Well, even the least expensive t-shirt seems to provide good protection.*

Comment: Glass blocks UV light. So I think it's better to buy cheap glass glasses than the plastic ones.

Comment: @user2824371 I dare  you to find a cheap pair of sunglasses with glass lenses.

Comment: @Carey Geogory Well, it exists in Egypt but I'm not sure about the quality of the glass. I feel like it's a material between glass and plastic. It's more like a glass.

Comment: I haven't seen a pair of sunglasses with glass lenses in many years. I wouldn't be so sure those glasses you describe have glass lenses.